# Mount remote filesystem and keep option to read and write protected files like everything in /etc/. Debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, remote-access

I would like an easy way to manage a **debian** server. I have ssh, an openvpn connection, X11 and sftp. X11 is not that comfortable as it is slow and I would prefer the app to run on my machine for this reason. With this, only the saving of files would have the delay.
I would like to have the whole file system mounted somewhere, ex.: /mnt/debianserver/ on my desktop, so that I could edit configuration files with VSCode by:

```
### My desktops terminal: 

cd /mnt/debianserver/etc/nginx/conf.d
sudo code     # sudo ??? I really don't know how permissions would work.
```

Now the VSCode would run on my desktop files but would load from remote debian server, I could edit them localy and as smoothly as allways.

I hope it is clear that what I would like to achieve is a way to work with remote filesystem as easily as with the local one.
If mounting and nfs is not the way to go or there is no possible answer than please let me know.

Comment: Checkout SSHFS. It's probably what you want. You can even remap UID and GID so, that permissions don't interfere.

Comment: But from experience I would rather suggest, that you start getting comfortable with terminal texteditors like nano or vim or something.... ))% of the times it's simply waaaay faster.

Comment: Thank you @Malik. SSHFS sounds awesome, but when trying to get it going I met with some issuse, it seems not to do anything... with -d switch i get  
"FUSE library version: 2.9.9  
nullpath_ok: 0  
nopath: 0  
utime_omit_ok: 0  
"
and nothing more until.

CUSTOM PORT!!!! Specify it with -p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSHFS is an answer I was looking for. It allows me to safely mount remote filesystem.
Here are links to tutorials on how to make this work:
[digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh),
[ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412477/mount-remote-directory-using-ssh)

Remember it is done over SSH so you have to specify all ssh options that you use to connect like via normal ssh connection.

```
mkdir /mnt/myserver

sudo apt-get install sshfs

# Short
sshfs user@A.B.C.D:/ /mnt/myserver

# more options: port, key file, fuse options
sudo sshfs -p xxxx -o allow_other,default_permissions,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user@A.B.C.D:/ /mnt/myserver

#################################################################
-d   -o debug          enable debug output (implies -f)
-o allow_other         allow access to other users
-o default_permissions enable permission checking by kernel
```

If command runs with no effect let it timeout on its own, maybe you will get a valuable debug message like: `port 22 timeout`.

There is also extension for **vscode** called: **Remote - SSH** from Microsoft which is basically allows you to open a remote folder via **SSH**.